# How to select the ' attribute' that created from count() as

Tags: sql

need help here with database sql.
how do i select the ord? can i do avg(ord) with that?

```
SELECT orderid,count(productid) as 'ord'
FROM orderdetails 
group by orderid;
```

Comment: Need some sample table data and expected output.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to take the average of a count(), it only has 1 value.

Comment: OrderID    ProductID
 10248           11   
 10248           42  
 10248           72   
 10249           14

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals. Use double quotes for column aliases, e.g. `"ord"`, or simply skip the delimiting (just `ord`.)

Comment: To give a complete example for jarlh's comment, `count(productid) as ord`

Comment: my orderid have 001,002,003 and each orderid can repeat for buy diff product .eg 001 buy chair 001 buy table..thn i count hw many times it have order in one orderid..eg 001 gt 2 times

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: Are you saying you want the average number of products per order across multiple orders?  So, if order one has 2 chairs and 1 table, order two has 4 chairs, order three has 8 chairs and 2 tables then you have an average of (2 + 4 + 8) / 3 = 4.66 chairs per order and (1 + 2) / 2 = 1.5 tables per order.  Is this what you are trying to find?

Comment: I agree with @SciGuyMcQ on his analysis. that's one approach. Or are you looking to get an average of products per order?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT avg(ord) FROM (
    SELECT orderid,count(productid) as 'ord'
    FROM orderdetails 
    group by orderid
);
```